# custom cells with drawRect: and setNeedsDisplay methods

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drawing, drawrect

there are 3 settings, in my app, that can be change the drawing of a cell.
By default, a cell of my table view show the name and the cost of an object... Changing these 3 setting, an user can choose to show a description or a link insted of cost.
I wrote a lot of code and now, my app can change cell's drawing without quit from it...
My problem is the drawing is changed only for new objects added but old objects don't change!
How can I do to change also the old cell's drawing without quit from app?

This is the code of my cell (i'm using setNeedsDisplay and drawRect methods):

```
#import "WishTableCell.h"


@implementation WishTableCell

@synthesize wish;
@synthesize imageView;
@synthesize nomeLabel;
@synthesize label;
@synthesize costoLabel;
@synthesize linkDescLabel;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 11, 28, 28)];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        [self.contentView addSubview:imageView];

        nomeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 8, 235, 22)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:nomeLabel];

        if ([NSLocalizedString(@"CostoCella", @"") isEqualToString:@"Costo:"]) {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 28, 40, 16)];
        }
        else {
            label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 28, 35, 16)];
        }
        [self.contentView addSubview:label];

        if ([NSLocalizedString(@"CostoCella", @"") isEqualToString:@"Costo:"]) {
            costoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 28, 185, 16)];
        }
        else {
            costoLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(93, 28, 195, 16)];
        }
        [self.contentView addSubview:costoLabel];

        linkDescLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 28, 235, 16)];
        [self.contentView addSubview:linkDescLabel];

        self.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        UIImage *rowBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBg.png"];
        ((UIImageView *)self.backgroundView).image = rowBackground;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)setWish:(Wish *)newWish {
    if (newWish != wish) {
        [wish release];
        wish = [newWish retain];
    }

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    NSLog(@"DrawRect called!");

    nomeLabel.text = wish.nome;
    nomeLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
    nomeLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.039 green:0.4 blue:0.737 alpha:1.0];
    nomeLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    nomeLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nomeLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    nomeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    label.text = NSLocalizedString(@"CostoCella", @"");
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.262 green:0.258 blue:0.258 alpha:1.0];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    costoLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    costoLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.262 green:0.258 blue:0.258 alpha:1.0];
    costoLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    costoLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    costoLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    costoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    linkDescLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0];
    linkDescLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.262 green:0.258 blue:0.258 alpha:1.0];
    linkDescLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    linkDescLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    linkDescLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    linkDescLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dettagliView"] isEqualToString:@"costoView"]) {

        linkDescLabel.hidden = YES;
        label.hidden = NO;
        costoLabel.hidden = NO;

        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"valutaCosto"] isEqualToString:@"Euro"]) {
            NSString *costo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"€ %@", wish.costo];
            costoLabel.text = costo;
        }
        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"valutaCosto"] isEqualToString:@"Dollaro"]) {
            NSString *costo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"$ %@", wish.costo];
            costoLabel.text = costo;
        }
        if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"valutaCosto"] isEqualToString:@"Sterlina"]) {
            NSString *costo = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"£ %@", wish.costo];
            costoLabel.text = costo;
        }
    }
    else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dettagliView"] isEqualToString:@"descrizioneView"]) {

        label.hidden = YES;
        costoLabel.hidden = YES;
        linkDescLabel.hidden = NO;

        linkDescLabel.text = wish.descrizione;
    }
    else if ([[defaults objectForKey:@"dettagliView"] isEqualToString:@"urlView"]) {

        label.hidden = YES;
        costoLabel.hidden = YES;
        linkDescLabel.hidden = NO;

        linkDescLabel.text = wish.link;
    }

    if (wish.categoria == nil)
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"personale.png"];

    if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Abbigliamento"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abbigliamento.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Casa"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"casa.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Cibo"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cibo.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Divertimento"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"divertimento.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Elettronica"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"elettronica.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Hobby"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"hobby.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Internet"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"internet.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Regali"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"regali.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Ufficio"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ufficio.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Viaggi"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"viaggi.png"];

    else if ([wish.categoria isEqualToString:@"Personale"])
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"personale.png"];
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [wish release];
    [imageView release];
    [nomeLabel release];
    [costoLabel release];
    [linkDescLabel release];
    [label release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Thanks a lot for the attention!
Matthew

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call [NSTableView reloadData] function, and set the drawing properties in the delegate method (cellForRowAtIndexPath).

Comment: I use this code in cellForRowAtIndexPath method: http://is.gd/hU5vU What can I do?

Comment: When some draw property changed, call a reloadData, which will reload the whole table, and update the cells.

Comment: Do you mean to use [self.tableView reloadData] ?

Comment: Yes. i guess it will refresh the cells

Comment: Ok... I'll try this method :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you also can use interface to create the cell (.xib), then you do not need write so many assign property code....

Comment: I tried to use IB to design my cells but I prefer to write code because it is more flexible than xib files...